# How to export content of blog posts for future migration?

Tags: powershell, migration, export, blog, content-migration

I would like to export the content of all blogs (excluding personal blogs) in SharePoint 2013 on prems. The purpose of that is to migrate later in a different platform. 
Is there any **out of the box** way to do that? In particular, is there any powershell script that gets the blog posts of each blog in every Site and store that in a file like txt, csv, xml or even docx?

I am not sure what is the target platform. I've already tried to search for an export to a general format but nothing came up. Using sharepoint paid addons is not an option at the moment. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example how to do it with BlogML
https://blogs.msmvps.com/cgross/2009/09/05/migrating-your-sharepoint-blog/

Now using PowerShell should be feasible as well. You don't need to have specific one for Blog. Blogs are essentially list items. So you need to look a script to export list items. (depending on columns you use you should on your local drive create some xml document with values for Title, Category etc for each entry) then you will be able to use those files for import.

You can export them to excel (this is native option for every list, just ensure you have the body column in the view) but from what i remember the pictures are not exported this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it by using the easiest method: export to excel