# Import BlogML Data (Blog) to SharePoint Online Modern Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, modern-experience

We plan to migrate a SharePoint 2016 on premise Blog to SharePoint Online Modern Sites.

A SharePoint Blog can be exported via BlogML (see this for further information: [How to export content of blog posts for future migration?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259224/how-to-export-content-of-blog-posts-for-future-migration?r=SearchResults&s=1|51.0290))

**How to Import BlogML Export to SharePoint Online Modern Sites? Is there a way to accomplish this. If not - is there another way for migration of a SharePoint Blog to Modern SharePoint?**